# How to get an instance from a factory based on a parameter

Tags: c#

I have an interface

```
public interface ITaxService
{
   public DateTime ValidFrom { get; }
   public DateTime ValidUntil { get; }
   public decimal GetTax(decimal taxableAmount);
}
```

I have some concrete classes the implement this interface

```
    class TaxService2019 : ITaxService
    {
        public DateTime ValidFrom { get { return new DateTime(2019, 1, 1); } }
        public DateTime ValidUntil { get { return new DateTime(2019, 12, 31); } }

        public decimal GetTax(decimal taxableAmount)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class TaxService2020 : ITaxService
    {
        public DateTime ValidFrom { get { return new DateTime(2020, 1, 1); } }
        public DateTime ValidUntil { get { return new DateTime(2020, 12, 31); } }

        public decimal GetTax(decimal taxableAmount)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Finally I have a factory which gets me the right service based on a date.

```
public static class Factory
    {
        static List<Type> TaxTypes;

        static Factory()
        {
            RegisterTypes();
        }

        private static void RegisterTypes()
        {
            TaxTypes = new List<Type>();
            TaxTypes.Add(typeof(TaxService2019));
            TaxTypes.Add(typeof(TaxService2020));
        }
        public ITaxService GetTaxService(DateTime legalDate)
        {
            // What to put here?
        }
```

Now I can't decide how to elegantly get the right service. I have tried 3 things:

1. Else-if list for every date range

```
if(new DateTime(2019,1,1) <= legalDate && legalDate <= new DateTime(2019,12,31))
{
    return new TaxService2019();
}
etc...
```

Seems bad to maintain.

2. Loop over every type in the list, instantiating them, read the dates and then compare them to return the right instance. Worst case I have instantiated n classes to find 1.
   Seems to have bad performance (very resource/time hungry)
3. Use some reflections. In this case I would add public static DateTimes to the concrete classes. Value would then be retrieved via `type.GetProperty("date").GetValue(type)`. The problem here would be that now there are 2 properties that return the same value + there is no way I can enforce someone to put the static variables in the concrete classes. This seems like the ugliest of possibilities.

How would you elegantly solve this problem?

Comment: Can you create instances instead of registering the types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, for example:

```
public static class Factory
{
    static List<(ITaxService service, Func<ITaxService> factory)> TaxDesc;

    static Factory()
    {
        RegisterTypes();
    }

    private static void RegisterTypes()
    {
        TaxDesc = new List<(ITaxService service, Func<ITaxService> factory)>
        {
            (new TaxService2019(), () => new TaxService2019())
        };
    }
    
    public static ITaxService GetTaxService(DateTime legalDate)
    {
        foreach (var taxDesc in TaxDesc)
        {
            if(taxDesc.service.ValidFrom  <= legalDate && legalDate < taxDesc.service.ValidUntil)
            {
                return taxDesc.factory();
            }
        }
        
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Better option can be using DI container, many of them allow multiple registrations for interface and allow resolving collection of interface, so you will not need to bother about the parameter injection into `TaxService` if needed.